# Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::getSpecificOptions()

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, error, magento2-migration-tool

I'm getting the following error when listing the products in a category:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::getSpecificOptions() in /var/www/html/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php on line 297
```

It's just the standard page that the topmenu takes you to when clicking on a category. Could anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento expects all attributes that are used for configurable products to use the `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table` source model. That's the one used if you create a "Dropdown" attribute manually in the backend and specify the possible options.

You used an attribute with the "boolean" source model ("Yes/No") as configurable attribute, IMHO it is a bug in Magento that this was possible in the first place as long as they don't support that.

You have to change the attribute to "Dropdown" and add "Yes" and "No" as possible options.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Must have been due to importing from Magento 1.9 using the data migration tool?

Comment: If the products were imported with the data migration tool, it probably was possible to use boolean attributes for configurable products in Magento 1.9 and they should add support for it again.